# laravel 9 admin super admin and user without package

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create User Admin and Super admin roles in my project. I'm trying to learn by myself.

create_roles_table.php

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

create_roles_user_table.php

```
class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
}
```

App\User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Role')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function authorizeRoles($roles)
    {
      if ($this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
        return true;
      }
      abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
      if (is_array($roles)) {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
          if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
      if ($this->roles()->where(‘name’, $role)->first()) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
}
```

Middleware\CheckRole.php

```
class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

AdminController

```
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('role:ROLE_ADMIN');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.home');
    }
}
```

views/admin/home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Admin Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    This is Admin Dashboard. You must be privileged to be here !
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('/superadmin', 'SuperAdminController@index');

Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

I try to do in this project so that there is the user the administrator and the super admin. I added what you see in the code but I feel like I'm missing things, I don't know what to add in the migration of user and role so that it can identify if it's an admin user or super admin. Currently I register, I register as a user but I would like to do so that if in the database a user is admin that he has access to the pages for admins and the other pages, while the user has the access as the user space. What am I missing in my code to make it work?

Comment: Are you doing any dynamic roles and permissions in your project ?

Comment: @Sujith Sandeep I don't know what is it dynamic roles and permissions, i'm noob. In first time i try to do for user can  have access to user space admin to admin and user space and super admin have access in all website. for when someone register i can do him admin or super admin

Comment: @Sujith Sandeep I try to do role and permissions without package, can you talk me what i need to add in migration user and in other part of code for admin super admin and user work. I mean for when register first user this is superadmin and others are users?

Comment: What I am asking is, Do you need roles alone or you need permissions also ?

Comment: @Sujith Sandeep i just need for when first users register it's super admin, and after all who register it's users. And for only super admin can have access in all website and user have only access to user space

Comment: Check my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Let me explain some basic things.

Users -> The users who are going to access your application.(i.e., superadminname, adminname)

Roles -> The roles who will be under your application(Super admin, Admin). There will be multiple users under the same role. The roles will be mapped with users.

Permissions -> The permission that is accessible for the particular role('Create user', 'Edit user', 'Delete User'). The super admin can have all the 3 privileges. But the admin can have only create and edit option and not the delete option. The permissions will be mapped to roles.

If you need only roles, The migrations should be roles and role_users. If you need permissions also, Then you can go with permissions and permission_role.

```
 // Schema to create roles table
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

// Schema to create role_users table
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);
        });

    // Schema to create permissions table
    Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


    // Schema to create permission_role table
    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

        $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
    });
```

Comment: Please do upvote and make the answer correct if you are satisfied.

Comment: Ok thanks you very much i have added this tables, what i need to do other for when first users register it's super admin, and after all who register it's users. And for only super admin can have access in all website and user have only access to user space

Comment: That is a very wide question. You need to retrict it in the frontend. First of all,  You need to take the role of the user. And then you need to take what are all permissions that is provided for that particular role and then you need to store it in session or local storage and then finally, You need to retrict it in frontend.

Comment: have all view, i have home, super admin, admin view. i just need for this register, for user can be admin or superadmin with access for superadmin,admin and user

Comment: Then the registration page should be common where everyone will have access to it...